# Unable to run shell script from AzureDevops pipeline

Tags: azure, shell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am new to AzureDevops pipelines. I have a simple task, I want to run a shell script which is residing in my azure git repo.

```
    steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline' # Optional. Options: filePath, inline
    #filePath: ./TestProject
    #arguments: # Optional

- script: 
    pwd
    set +x token.sh
    sh token.sh
```

Build is getting successful but I don't see it has picked the sh file:

```
Generating script.


10(node:3269) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr


11(node:3269) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr


12(node:3269) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr


13Script contents:


14pwd set +x token.sh sh token.sh


15(node:3269) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr


16========================== Starting Command Output ===========================


17(node:3269) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr


18(node:3269) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr


19(node:3269) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr


20/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/33bdee3d-19de-47b6-8eab-01124cb0a0ed.sh


21/home/vsts/work/1/s


22Finishing: CmdLine
```

Build is successful but there is no log for sh execution.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in three tasks(Command line
,Shell Exec
,Bash
) with a simple `.sh` file sample , every thing work well in these tasks , sh file executes normally.

[image]
[image]

So can you share the `token.sh` sample file for further investigation? If there is any personal privacy information, please protect it.

Comment: First of all, I wasn't able to find agent job while creating pipeline. 2nd, I want to execute it on remote computer, how do I achieve it?

Comment: 1st:Here I use the [classic editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb0gb.png),you are using yaml, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#job).;2nd: Run shell command on remote machine,you can refer to this [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops)

Comment: @akshay vithalkar Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.